# How to transfer SQL data from one table to another using Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two tables in my database that contain the same columns. TBL one and TBL two which is history table. When I am entering data into TBL 1, I want to move all data from TBL 1 to Tbl 2 (as history data) using EF Core 2.2.

I don't want to write unnecessary loops to make the code ugly.

```
var MyEntity = new MyEntities();
var TBL1 = MyEntity.TBL1.Find();
var TBL2 = new TBL2();

TBL2.CurrentValues.SetValues(TBL1); 
//CurrentValues is not accept in code. Giving me build error

MyEntity.TB2.Add(data2);
MyEntity.TB1.Remove(data1);
MyEntity.SaveChanges();
```

All I need is copy SQL data from table 1 to table 2 using EF and avoiding loops. Any example with mapper or anything which works will help.

Comment: EF is *not really suited* to handle bulk operations, like copying a whole table of data. This is still where "raw" T-SQL shines.

Comment: Completely agree with @marc_s.

Comment: Learn something about projections :)

Comment: @Kaps26: I know the question is old, but you got 2 answers - can you mark one as accepted, please?

Answer (score 0):

Add a navigation property to your TBL2 model:

```
public TBL1 TBL1 { get; set; }
```

Add a projection to your TBL1 model like this:

```
public static Expression<Func<TBL1, TBL2>> Projection
{
    return tbl1 => new TBL2
    {
        Prop1 = tbl1.Prop1,
        Prop2 = tbl1.Prop2,
        TBL1 = tbl1,
    };
}
```

And use the projection to have instances of TBL1 and TBL2 like this:

```
var MyEntity = new MyEntities();
var tbl2 = MyEntity.TBL1.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(TBL1.Projection).SingleOrDefault();
vat tbl1 = tbl2.TBL1;

MyEntity.TB2.Add(tbl2);
MyEntity.TB1.Remove(tbl1);
MyEntity.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want to change your table model just for copying data, you want to copy from one table to another, possibly to a different database.

So you could try it with something like this. Use ClearTable to make the target table empty, then copy the items:

```
void ClearTable<T>(System.Data.Linq.Table<T> tbl, bool submitChanges = true)
where T : class
{
    tbl.DeleteAllOnSubmit(tbl);
    if (submitChanges) ctxSrc.SubmitChanges();
}

void CopyTable<T>(System.Data.Linq.Table<T> srcTbl, 
                  System.Data.Linq.Table<T> tgtTbl, bool submitChanges = true)
    where T : class
{
    ClearTable(tgtTbl, submitChanges);
    foreach (var element in srcTbl.Select(s => s).ToList())
    {
        tgtTbl.Append(element);
    }
    if (submitChanges) ctxTgt.SubmitChanges();
}
```

**Example 1:** Copy from one table to another (same database)

```
CopyTable(ctxSrc.Products1, ctxSrc.Products2);
```

**Example 2:** Copy from one database to another

```
CopyTable(ctxSrc.Products, ctxTgt.Products);
```

This assumes that you have two database contexts: `ctxSrc` and `ctxTgt` and you want to copy from the source context to the target context.

---

**Notes:**

- The code above deletes items from the target table before copying. Comment the `ClearTable` call if you just want to append data.
- The example doesn't regard dependencies such as foreign key relationshios. You have to add that to the code if required. For example, copying tables in the right order is important. If you have a foreign key pointing to another table you have to copy that table first. Similar rules apply to deletion of rows which contain foreign keys.
- If you have many elements, consider to submit more often. This example will hold all elements in memory before it submits. You could achieve this through paging. You can append `.Skip(n)` and `.Take(m)` methods for this purpose.
- Other than SQL does Entity Framework (Core) not know any true bulk operations. Even `tbl.DeleteAllOnSubmit(tbl)`, which looks like one (it is an integrated method), does internally loop through all elements in order to remove them.